# Show that $\sqrt { n } \le \alpha (n)\le \frac { n+1 }{ 2 } $ with $n\in\mathbb{N}. $

Tags: number-theory

$\alpha(n)$ is the average of the positive divisors of n.

I think that $\alpha(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{\tau(n)}$

as $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the positive divisors of n and $\tau(n)$ the number of positive divisors n

It is right?

I do not understand how to demonstrate the inequality

Comment: Do you know any other properties of $\alpha(n)$ or $\tau(n)$ or $\sigma(n)$?? If you think the result in your question is difficult to prove you should first try some obvious relations

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a start, which doesn’t require anything fancy about the divisor function definitions:

Notice that every divisor $d$ of $n$ that’s smaller than $\sqrt{n}$ must have a partnering divisor $k>\sqrt{n}$ so that $dk=n$. Then use $d+k\geq 2\sqrt{dk} =2\sqrt{n}$, so that the average over all divisors is at least $\sqrt{n}$.

The upper bound  can be derived with analogous reasoning.